# A namespace cannot directly contain members

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm very new to unity and coding ( c# specifically ) and when I was working on the moving I kept getting this error . I've tried researching and looking at other questions but wasn't sure on what to do, so if you can help me that will be very helpful. [the errors in unity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fginz.png)  [here is the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8akaX.png)

Comment: Could you please post your code as text?

Comment: Remove the Close brace in the line after 'MonoBehaviour' and add that to the Last Line. The Class is empty and you added the method in the Namespace.

Comment: The `{ }` after `MonoBehavior` is opening and closing your class definition. Everything else you've typed is subsequently, directly in the name space which is not allowed. Move the `}` to after the `}` of `Update()`

Comment: Also as a recommendation to new member, please don't post code in images, it makes it hard for people to debug. Please copy/paste it into your question correctly formatted :)

Comment: Actually it is not only a recommendation but the rule for code to be posted as text formatted using the `{ }` button

Answer (score 4):

You need to wrap your code inside your class.

```
public class NewBehaviorScript : MonoBehaviour
{
   public float forwardForce = 2000f;
   ...etc
}
```

You can learn more about namespaces here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/namespaces/

Your code is like this

```
public class NewBehaviorScript : MonoBehaviour
    { }
       public float forwardForce = 2000f;
       ...etc
```

Outside your class is the namespace in your case, this is why your compiler complains.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the "}" after Monobehavoir and paste it at the end of your script. Your code should look like this:

---

```
    public class NewBehaviorScript : MonoBehavior
    {
        private int myVariable = 1;

        private void myMethod()
        {

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have added a property or field outside of a class. Probably by mistake. e.g.

```
namespace MyNamespace
{
    //this is invalid because properties MUST be inside a class
    public string PropertyOne {get;set;}

    public class MyClass
    {
        public string PropertyTwo {get;set;}
    }
}
```